Error after recreating cloud recognition gameobject & image target gameobject
I had this error about Cloud Recognition but didn't understand the problem where exactly.
The error popped up without no reason I only recreate the cloud recognition gameObject & image target and removed the old ones & replaced what is needed there was no changing in the scripts every thing is the same.
Exception in callback: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEngine.Debug:LogErrorFormat (string,object[])
Vuforia.Internal.Utility.UnityLogger:LogError (string,object[])
Vuforia.Internal.Utility.Log:Error (string,object[])
Vuforia.Utility.ExtensionMethods.DelegateHelper:InvokeDelegate (System.Delegate,object[])
Vuforia.Utility.ExtensionMethods.DelegateHelper:InvokeWithExceptionHandling<Vuforia.CloudRecoBehaviour/CloudRecoSearchResult> (System.Action`1<Vuforia.CloudRecoBehaviour/CloudRecoSearchResult>,Vuforia.CloudRecoBehaviour/CloudRecoSearchResult)
Vuforia.CloudRecoBehaviour/<>c__DisplayClass42_1:<OnRecoObservations>b__1 (System.Action`1<Vuforia.CloudRecoBehaviour/CloudRecoSearchResult>)
Vuforia.Internal.Utility.ExtensionMethods.IEnumerableExtensionMethods:ForEach<System.Action`1<Vuforia.CloudRecoBehaviour/CloudRecoSearchResult>> (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.Action`1<Vuforia.CloudRecoBehaviour/CloudRecoSearchResult>>,System.Action`1<System.Action`1<Vuforia.CloudRecoBehaviour/CloudRecoSearchResult>>)
Vuforia.CloudRecoBehaviour/<>c__DisplayClass42_0:<OnRecoObservations>b__0 ()
Vuforia.CloudRecoBehaviour:Update ()

If anyone has any idea about it or had something like it can help me? THANK YOU IN ADVANCE
I was fixing an issue about image target scaling by recreating the image target, and this problem popped up.

When I get this, it's usually because my deleted GameObject was used in a public field of some script or component of another GameObject. Look through your GameObjects in the inspector to see if any public fields are missing the Cloud Recognition Image Target

i check all of them & i actually re-created the scene even al over again but still popping out
